# OpenAI API ошибка 403

Tags: python, chatgpt, chatgpt-api, python-openai

Есть такой код

```
def gpt(type_: str) -> str:
    """

    Использование GPT

    """

    openai.api_key = GPT_TOKEN

    print("start generating")
    print(type_)
    print("'"+prompts.get(type_)+"'")

    completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompts.get(type_)}])

    print("end generating")

    return str(completion.choices[0].message.content)
```

type_ - это выбор из словаря промптов, сам список prompts это сам словарь с промптами, проблема в том что при вызове этого кода появляется ошибка 403

```
HTTP code 403 from API (<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

и далее просто идет html код

как это возможно исправить

причем раньше код работал, это на днях начало выдавать ошибку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Решение для этого безобразия нашел пока, что только одно. Это VPN на пк

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ну лучше так чем никак

Answer (score 0):

HTML возвращает не openai, а cloudflare всем русским ip-адресам, просто openai заблочили доступ из РФ теперь и по api, но решение до нелепого простое: в старых версиях либы можно просто прописывать:

```
openai.proxy = {любой прокси кроме РФ}
```

, а в новых версиях - в параметрах `AsyncOpenAI` можно предать:

```
http_client=httpx.AsyncClient(proxies={любой прокси кроме РФ})
```